# scala dataframe column value conditional computation

Tags: scala, dataframe

I need help with the correct and best possible syntax for below Scala df:

```
//this works:    
var df2 = df1.withColumn("score", when(col("a")===0, (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)).otherwise(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7))
```

I am looking for a better and more compact syntax here something like:

```
// does not work, error: col("a") which is a column cannot be equated to an int
var df2 = df1.withColumn("score", 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + (if (col("a")===0) 7 else 0))
```

The reason I need to do this is because using "when" works but the code line is too long and difficult to read and maintain and there is too much duplication of writing `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6` over and again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `col("a") === lit(0)` or write an udf

```
df1.withColumn("score", udfTest(col("a")))

val udfTest: UserDefinedFunction = 
  udf {
    (columnA: Int) => {1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + (if (columnA == 0) 0 else 7)}
  }
```